# kGraft ,Live Kernel patching in suse

Tags: linux, kernel, suse, patch

Can anyone did Kernel live patching using Kgraft in SLES 11 or 12 ?
Is there any procedure to be followed ?
How can we verify the kernel vulnerability fixes after Kgraft patching ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live patching is available only on SLE12+
Is sold as SLE12 extension so you need valid key and register this to get Live patches.

SUSE offers 60day trial on [Live patching purchase page](https://www.suse.com/products/live-patching/how-to-buy)

Live patching is controlled by `kgr` tool:

```
# kgr 
Error: no command provided

Usage: /usr/bin/kgr [-h][-v] COMMAND
Query and manipulate kGraft patching status.

Commands:
    status:    display the overall status of kGraft patching
    patches:   display the list of loaded patches
    blocking:  list processes that are preventing kGraft patching
           from finishing
    poke:      move forward with the kGraft patching by sending
           STOP and CONT signal to the pending processes

Options:
    -h     print this help
    -v     more detailed output

Report bugs at https://bugzilla.suse.com/.
```

and verification of applied patches:

```
 # kgr -v patches
 kgraft_patch_2_2_1
     active: 1
     RPM: kgraft-patch-3_12_62-60_64_8-default-2-2.1.x86_64
     CVE: CVE-2016-8666 CVE-2016-6480
     bug fixes and enhancements: (none)
```

For own verification of fixed bug you might try bug reproducer if exists. ( not recommended way , SUSE's QA-Maintenace tests this patches very extensively before release to it customers)